# What is the order of redirection in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to take input from file input.txt and write output of execution to output.txt  What is the right order?  The below does not work.

```
./a.out < input.txt > output.txt
```

**EDIT**

Do I have to wait for execution to complete for it to be written? I usually break in the middle to see if o/p is getting written as run time is very high.

**CLARIFICATION:**

This C program (P1) iterates through a loop and feeds the loop value x to a system() call which calls another C program (P2) using `./P2 < x`.  Program P2 executes for each value of x and outputs to screen.  I want to the complete output of both programs to output.txt.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The order is irrelevant. If it "does not work", there is another problem. Please describe exactly what result you expect, and what you get instead.

Comment: Doesn't matter, at all.

Comment: What is the output when you run ./a.out < input.txt ..... the command you have should work fine if the data, permissions, and code is correct.

Comment: output.txt gets created but is empty.  If I remove "> output.txt", I get results on the screen.  ./a.out prints results to screen.  I just wanted that to be redirected to output.txt.

Comment: Maybe a.out writes to stderr and not to stdout. See if that's the case by using "2> output.txt"

Comment: Notice that cat reads from stdin and writes to stdout, so you can do "cat < input.txt > output.txt" and it'll work as you want - to prove to your self that this works.

Comment: @koodawg Yes it works with cat but not with the C program.

Comment: @sleske Added details to question.

Comment: If you don't realize it, in "./P2 < x", the shell expects x to be a file, not a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're killing the command before it finishes, this is probably a buffering issue. Line-buffered terminal output and block-buffered file output are default behaviors in the C stdio library, so redirection can cause output to be buffered until a few kilobytes have been written.

Some programs have a command line option to force line-buffered or unbuffered output. They do this by calling `setvbuf`. If that `a.out` is a program you wrote, you could add`setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);`

If the program is not yours and you can't recompile it, there is a utility called `stdbuf` that might help, as in `stdbuf -oL ./a.out < in > out`

`stdbuf` is kind of a kludge though. I wouldn't use it unless there is no other option.

Comment: Excellent.  As suspected, a buffering issue.